# In which case `ParameterizedType#getActualTypeArguments` return an array which has more than one elements

Tags: java

I tried to get the classtype in the generic,and code below works:

```
@Test
public void test3() throws NoSuchFieldException {
    Class<?> clazz = (Class<?>) ((ParameterizedType)Role.class.getDeclaredField("users")
            .getGenericType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    assert clazz.equals(User.class) : "error!";
}

static class Role {
    public List<User> users;
}
static class User {

}
```

So, I learned something about `ParameterizedType`.

And I want to know in which case `ParameterizedType#getActualTypeArguments` return an array which has more than one elements.I tried a lot of cases, but all the results are an array of size 1.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't something like `Map<String, Integer>` have two type arguments, `String` and `Integer`? Isn't that what it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It return an array of more than one element if you have several generic parameters like in Map.

Example :

```
@Test
public void exampleTest() {
    Map<Integer, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) myMap.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    System.out.println("Array of actual types : " + Arrays.toString(type.getActualTypeArguments()));
}
```

And the output is :

> Array of actual types : [K, V]